# multiplicating big numbers as arrays C++

Tags: c++

I'am doing a program that multiples big numbers stored as strings. How can I store every line of multiplication separately in my code below(like multiplication line 1, multiplication line2), so i can add them up like in simple shool mathematic?

```
string findCount(string str1, string str2){
    // Before proceeding further, make sure length
    // of str2 is larger.
    if (str1.length() > str2.length())
        swap(str1, str2);

    // Take an empty string for storing result
    string str = "";
    // Calculate lenght of both string
    int n1 = str1.length(), n2 = str2.length();      //n1 is the smaller one

    // Reverse both of strings
    reverse(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    reverse(str2.begin(), str2.end());

    int carry = 0;
    for(int j =0; j<n1; j++){
        for (int i=0; i<n2; i++){
            int multiply = ((str1[j]-'0')*(str2[i]-'0')+carry);
            str.push_back(multiply%10 + '0');

            carry = multiply/10;
        }
    }
    if(carry)
        str.push_back(carry +'0');

    reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
    return str;

}
```

Comment: the % wan't work becouse i need the 2 from 24 not 4

Comment: You can obtain the 2 from 24 as `int a(24); int dec = (a-a%10)/10;`

Comment: I dont have a problem to obtain the 2 my problem is diffrent

Comment: What do you mean by _every line of the multiplication_? Are these as many lines as n1 digits?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i mean.

Comment: Do you also need the result? In this case, the returned string would have a size equal to n1 number of digits +1.

Comment: i need to have the result so i can input two numbers as strings and the muliply them and show the result

Comment: Add the lines as you go. There is no need to add them all at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your function to get what I think is the expected result:

```
string findCount(string str1, string str2)
{
    // Before proceeding further, make sure length
    // of str2 is larger.
    if (str1.length() > str2.length())
        swap(str1, str2);

    // Take an empty string for storing result
    string str = "";
    // Calculate lenght of both string
    int n1 = str1.length(), n2 = str2.length();      //n1 is the smaller one

    // Reverse both of strings
    reverse(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    reverse(str2.begin(), str2.end());

    // Itarate small number
    string total;
    for(int j =0; j<n1; j++){

        // Reset carry
        int carry = 0;
        string aux;
        for (int i = 0;i<j;i++)
            aux.push_back('0');
        for (int i=0; i<n2; i++){
            int multiply = ((str1[j]-'0')*(str2[i]-'0')+carry);
            aux.push_back(multiply%10 + '0');
            carry = multiply/10;
        }
        if(carry)
            aux.push_back(carry +'0');

        // Add to toal
        /// Allocate space for result
        if (total.size() < aux.size())
        {
            for (int i = total.size(); i<aux.size(); i++) total.push_back('0');
        }
        // Add
        for (int i = 0;i<aux.size();i++)
        {
            int add = ((total[i] - '0') + (aux[i] - '0'));
            total[i] = (add%10 + '0');
            if (add/10 > 0)
            {
                if (i >= total.size())
                    total.push_back('0');
                total[i+1] = (((total[i+1] - '0') + (add/10)) + '0');
            }
        }

        // Reverse
        reverse(aux.begin(),aux.end());

        // Append
        string aux2 = total;
        reverse(aux2.begin(),aux2.end());
        str += aux;
        str += ("(" + aux2 +")");
        // New line
        str.push_back('\n');
    }
    reverse(total.begin(),total.end());
    str += total;
    return str;
}
```

Your initial code had the problem that you were only carrying at the end of the whole multiplication, not after each n1 digit.